# Silverstripe 3.1.2 is modifying anchor links

Tags: php, silverstripe

I tried to build tabs with jquery.
But i recognized that my links

```
<a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a>
```

are converted to

```
<a href="/#tab-1">Tab 1</a>
```

Because of the Slash at the beginning the tabs doesn't work.
Why is Silverstripe modifiying my anchor links and how can I stop it from doeing this??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On 2.4er setup I set in _config.php

```
SSViewer::setOption('rewriteHashlinks', false);
```

not tested with 3.x and the yml config layer

Comment: can you try, make it work the yml-way? somth like this (no tabs just space in /mysite/_config/config.yml)

 SSViewer:
   setOption:
     rewriteHashlinks: true

Comment: if i copy paste it, it doesn't work.
edit: doesn't matter which constellation I try. It doesn't work :/

can you tell me the advantages of using the yml file instead of config.php?

Comment: YML config are cached and so will give you a performance inscrease. Also, some of the old notation will most likely be depracated soon. Try this in your YML SSViewer.rewrite_hashlinks: false (Replacing the '.' with a new line and 2 spaces indentation, like for theme)

Comment: i tried this before. doesn't work.

thank you for the explanation. Is there a guide or something like this where i could look up how to convert my _config.php configurations to a yml?

Comment: did you ?flush the cache after updating the yml? Check the changelog http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/3.1/changelogs/3.1.0#static-properties-are-immutable-and-private-you-must-use-config-api there is all you need there

Comment: still did not try myself but this guy says: SSViewer: rewrite_hash_links: false 
https://github.com/redema/silverstripe-patchwork/blob/master/_config/patchwork.yml

Answer (score 4):

SSViewer::setOption() is deprecated in 3.2

Use one of the following examples to set rewrite_hash_links

**config.yml**

```
SSViewer:
  rewrite_hash_links: false
```

**_config.php**

```
Config::inst()->update('SSViewer', 'rewrite_hash_links', false);
```

(http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-SSViewer.html#_setOption)