# SilverStripe Append an anchor to the url a form submits to

Tags: forms, silverstripe

I've got a regular silverstripe Form() method in my controller.  It submits to a Submit() method as per the normal way of doing things.

On the page the form is in a tab and not displayed by default.

Is it possible to append an anchor to the URL the form submits to so that if validation fails, the form tab is displayed?

I have tried to do this by adding:

```
 $form->setFormAction($this->Link(). "/Submit#location-enquiry");
```

However the form does not seem to go to the Submit() method when doing that. Inspecting what's happening in chrome tools, it just posts to:

```
example/page/Submit
```

..with the anchor appended

How can i append the anchor and still process the form?

Comment: does this one help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20560951/silverstripe-3-1-2-is-modifying-anchor-links/20562209#20562209

Answer (score 1):

You can set if the form should be redirected back to the form name's hash **on validation errors**:

```
//false by default
$form->setRedirectToFormOnValidationError(true);
```

which will have the form's name appended in the redirect on errors:

```
return Director::redirect($pageURL . '#' . $this->FormName());
```

If the form does not have any errors, you could easily do the same in your processing method.

Comment: Director::redirect() is deprecated in 3.0 and up. You should use $this->redirect($url) on a controller.

Comment: yep, or `Controller::curr()->redirect()` outside a controller. The line is just copied from the `Form` class, where it handles the redirect...

Comment: So setting the setRedirectToFormOnValidationError to true redirects the form to #Form_Form and i can in this case adjust the front end code to use that.  I'm not following the second part on how to change the redirect url?