# Smooth scrolling not working in Silverstripe framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, silverstripe, smooth-scrolling

I am pulling my hair out trying to get any form of smoothscroll working for days now on the Silverstripe 3.6.3 framework. Anyone know why jquery plug in or simple javascript scroll will not work. Or is it just me. I've had it working on previous versions which I have copied with no joy. PHP7 apache etc.

So I went simple.

I have tried using this demo https://cferdinandi.github.io/smooth-scroll/

I put it onto a root file index.html and index.php on my domain. It works fine on these but when I put it onto the silverstripe template it doesn't respond the anchors work but no animation.

HELP....

Comment: have you included  `$SilverStripeNavigator` in your `.ss` file?

Comment: Do you get any JS errors in the console? Also check the network tab to see if your JS files get loaded at all.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps SS is rewriting your anchor-links ?

https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/templates/how_tos/disable_anchor_links/

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20560951/silverstripe-3-1-2-is-modifying-anchor-links/20562209#20562209